# Problem deploying Safari web extension to Mac App store

Tags: javascript, swift, app-store, safari-extension

I have followed the steps to deploy the safari extension to mac app store by creating an archive and then validating it. I received no error when validating. However when trying to "Distribute App" The following error is coming up in the last stage. -"Corrupted manifest file. The manifest.json file could not be read in Safari extension bundle"

The extension build is running as per expectations locally.
Please help

My manifest.json

```
{
  "author": "Author Name",
  "background": {
    "page": "index.html",
  },
  "version" : "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/img/logo-64-disabled.png",
    "default_title": "Title"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["assets/js/index.js", "assets/js/content.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com; object-src 'self'",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "Description",
  "homepage_url": "https://example.com",
  "icons": {
    "128": "assets/img/logo-128.png",
    "16": "assets/img/logo-16.png",
    "32": "assets/img/logo-32.png",
    "48": "assets/img/logo-64.png",
    "64": "assets/img/logo-64.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name",
  "options_ui": {
    "open_in_tab": false,
    "page": "assets/options.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>",
  ],
  "short_name": "Name",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["assets/*"]
}
```

Comment: You'll have to include some code before we can see what's wrong with it!

Comment: What is the swift tag for?